# Sudo apt-get install -f removed all packages from debian

Tags: linux, debian

I used

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This command removed all packages from my Debian 64 bit wheezy.
Even the core package as gnome application and chrome even I am not able to launch terminal.

I want to restore them . how can I?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know why some one did downvote?

Comment: The question is vague and missing important information - e.g.  how did you get into a position that you had to use ``apt-get install -f`` in the first place. It appears to be lacking in any research. Having said that, I wasn't the one to down vote it.

Comment: It is not about downvote, I just want to improve by knowing reason . I was installing a package using dpkg and it was unable to install due to dependencies, so I researched on Google and by following a forum thread I run the command without knowing it's affects.

Comment: ``apt-get install -f`` will try to fix the package dependencies of the installed system using whatever means necessarily. Usually this means just removing the broken package. It seems a bit strange that it would resort to removing unrelated packages.

Comment: What package was it you tried to install with dpkg?

Comment: There is no libcrypt library that I can see. Speculating that you replaced a library that a lot of applications depend on with a broken one, and ``apt-get install -f`` decided the best solution was to remove the library and everything that depended on the library.

Comment: Library name is libgcrypt11_1.5.3-5_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

This shows why it is important to understand what apt-get is about to do before you accept its recommendation. As sometimes, its recommended solution will be to remove everything, as you have discovered. It is not possible to tell why it came to this decision without more information.

You can use `apt-get install task-gnome-desktop` to reinstall the Gnome desktop. You will have to keep repeating this for the packages that are missing.

However, it is possible that the problem that caused apt-get to remove these packages in the first place is still present, and the above commands will fail. In which case you will need to investigate the errors you get.

Comment: Thanks @penguin. I ll follow